# Access a json object form views django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

i have tried a number of suggestions but need help.

in my views.py

```
def findnamesurname(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    obj =  Users.objects.all().values("first_name").filter(username=username)
    return HttpResponse(obj)
```

in my js

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "/findnamesurname",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
                "username": data,
            },

            success: function (data) {
            
            alert(JSON.stringify(data))

      }
        })
    }
```

I want to get first name please in a variable

How to access this object please.

Whet I alert I get:

```
 {'first_name': 'hello', 'last_name': 'there'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got your question right. But if you want to retrieve the first and last name of a user by its username, you first need to filter/search that user in the database. Then you can send the response by using JsonResponse.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.http import Http404


def findnamesurname(request):
    username = request.POST["username"]
    try:
        user = YourUserModel.objects.get(username=username).values(
            "first_name", "last_name"
        )
    except YourUserModel.DoesNotExists:
        raise Http404

    return JsonResponse(user)
```

Comment: Hi there please see [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 259ms

Comment: Provide a detailed error message or stack trace to see what the problem is.